# GWT listbox onmouseover tooltip

Tags: gwt, listbox, tooltip, mouseover

Id like to add tooltip to each item of a ListBox ?

Any idea ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: You will have text displayed over text. Bad idea. You can add additional information to each option directly if you have to. Like, "option 1: the most popular choice in our app".

Answer (score 3):

Since the `ListBox` doesn't expose it's `OptionElement` list, we'll need to get the underlying `SelectElement`.

```
    SelectElement selectElement = SelectElement.as(listBox.getElement());
```

From there, we just set the `title` on each `OptionElement`.

```
    NodeList<OptionElement> options = selectElement.getOptions();
    for (int i = 0; i < options.getLength(); i++) {
        options.getItem(i).setTitle("Hover text for item #" + i);
    }
```